# IIS Express not stopping when debug session ends

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, iis-express, asp.net-core-2.0

All of a sudden IIS Express no longer stops when I stop debugging a web site in Visual Studio 2017.

I'm not sure when this behaviour started, but I have the following setup:

- Visual Studio 15.5.2 (Has been repaired)
- IIS Express 10.0 x64 (Reinstalled)
- An ASP.Net Core 2 project targeting `net461`
- I have disabled "Enable edit and continue" in Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General

Not sure when this started happedning, maybe when I updated to the lastest VS version.

What more can I try?

Comment: Turning "Enable edit and continue" off is what actually *allows* this behavior.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Ok, yeah I've seen some contradictory information about this, so I've actually tried both...

Comment: All I know is that I actually *prefer* the behavior you seem to want to get rid of, and the way to keep IIS Express running after debugging ends is to uncheck that box.

Comment: FWIW, unchecking the box in options sets the default. There's a separate project-level setting of the same name in .NET Framework projects It's possible that it's unchecked there, despite changes you've made in options. Edit your project properties and check it. Ironically, edit and continue is not supported in .NET Core projects, so the behavior you want is the *only* behavior possible.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Well, the problem it is causing me is that sometimes I can't build and launch a new debug session since Visual Studio can't access some files because they are locked by another process (IIS Express is my guess).

And yes, that .NET Framework setting doesn't exist, since it is a .NET Core 2 project targeting .NET Framework 4.6.

What is weird is that this just started happening a couple of days ago. Nothing has changed in the project setup. The only thing I can think of was updating Visual Studio to the latest version.

Comment: Same annoying problem. Sorry but turning off the mentioned option doesn't work.

Comment: @daniherculano Yeah I still haven't found a solution. Please let me know if you figure something out :)

Comment: Neither checking or unchecking "Enable Edit and Continue" helps. In both cases the IIS web server continues to run when I end the debug session. Wtf Microsoft

Answer (score 14):

If **`Enable Edit and Continue`** is **unchecked**
Then `IIS Express` **stays running** even after debugging is stopped.

You can uncheck it if you want here:

> Right click your project **»** click `Properties` **»** select the `Web` tab » `Enable Edit and Continue` checkbox
>   [image]

Comment: Why? If VS stopped debugging, nothing to edit and continue! what am I missing?

Comment: @NourSabouny, The IIS Express is a web server, So it can stays running... You can play with the live website on your system and see the result of functionalities and change your code based on them while the website is not in debugging mode. So in some cases it can be useful. Also you can change the views and refresh the related pages and follow the changes in this mode too. Although I usually like to use  **Edit and Continue = ON** because it give me some useful abilities to change the code in Runtime and rerun it and see the result without restart the whole project.

Comment: JFC Microsoft, this has been driving me nuts for WEEKS. How about you either make this a separate checkbox (there are already two) or just add a line in the tooltip that explains that IIS Express will run the task to completion!

Answer (score 11):

**For .net Core web projects in Visual studio 2017**

If you add:

```
<AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
```

or:

```
<AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
```

in the first PropertyGroup in your project.csproj config you will alter the iis express behavior.

- **InProcess** will kill iis express after debug.
- If the setting is **missing** or set to **OutOfProcess** iis express will keep the process running.

-
*This setting updates the .vs\config\applicationhost.config of your solution and hostingModel="InProcess" will be added/removed to the iis express launch config for the project.*

```
  <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" hostingModel="InProcess" />
```

(You don't need to change the applicationhost.config, only for reference)

Comment: Perfect, especially as turning off edit/continue is a bit daft as it's useful :-)

Comment: It's working in VS2019, make sure to reopen the solutions or unload & reload the project.

Comment: @Palanikumar it doesn't required.

Comment: Which version(s) of AspNetCore is this valid for? I'm on 2.1 and it has no effect.

Answer (score 7):

There is an option to control the behaviour in Visual Studio.

Edit and Continue Location

[image]

The latest VS 2017 update must have turned it on.

When turning the marked option off again, IIS Express stops when ending the debugging session.

Comment: is this an answer or just a rant ?

Comment: This kind of looks like a good answer, so I deleted all the rant.

Comment: Thank you. Its a very valid answer now for VS 2017

Answer (score 5):

For .net Core web projects in Visual studio 2019

Right click your project » click Properties » select the Debug tab » Select the Hosting Model.

In Process: IIS Express will stop when you stop the debugger.
Out Of Process: IIS Express will continue after you stop the debugger.

[image]

Comment: I was searching for this since long time. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the not stopping of IIS Express in ASP.NET Core is by design: https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/3394#issuecomment-378307654

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2019:

Tools -> Options -> Project and Solutions -> Web Projects: "Stop debugger when browser window is closed".

Comment: can you verify that this actually does something in .net CORE 3.1 or any core for that matter VS 16.5.3 so latest as of this post...

Comment: This only works if you have `launchBrowser` set in your `launchSettings.json`.

Comment: I dont have this option in Web Projects

Answer (score -1):

If the issue appears sporadically (with no-reproducibility) it maybe an issue or bug somewhere on asp or vs, why not save the project, then kill directly the process and re-run it ?

Comment: It happens every debug session for me. Killing manually is the workaround that I am using, but it is a PITA and slows down the whole code-debug cycle.

Answer (score -1):

IIS Express keep the site on ( like an IIS ), you could go to your taskbar, right click on IIS Express Icon and you will be able to stop each site manually.