# IIS Express won't stop after debugging

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, iis-express

I have this problem with VS 2019 and IIS Express: we have a setup with an ASP.NET Core web app as backend and an Angular front end. How we develop is using VS Code for Angular app (served on localhost:4200) while running backend from VS 2019 using IIS Express.

What I noticed after I upgraded to VS version 16.11.5 (wasn't updating for months prior to this) is that IIS Express won't stop after I stop debugging on VS.

For example: I hit break point in POST method on BE but I don't want to continue and I just want whole thing to end (e.g. don't want to modify my test data) however angular app makes second call to the method (because that's what it do) and request is processed.

Meaning even when I stop debugging IIS Express still goes on. This is very uncomfortable to me especially when I need to trace bug in my code without doing mess in my data. I tried many suggestions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48115931/iis-express-not-stopping-when-debug-session-ends) however without any luck.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022 Visual Studio is not open sourced and many small pieces are not well documented, so your best option is to talk to Microsoft directly on such.

Comment: @LexLi that's what I wanted to avoid as I created some tickets for them in the past and they weren't much helpful :) but you have a point and I'll try that.